# RabbitMQ setPort causes ConnectionRefused

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq

I have a simple RabbitMQ example starts as follows :

```java
    private Channel channel;
    private ConnectionFactory connectionFactory;
    
    @Autowired
    public RabbitMqManager() {
        connectionFactory = new ConnectionFactory();
        connectionFactory.setHost("localhost");
        //connectionFactory.setPort(15672); // ERROR : this breaks rabbitmq connection
        try {
            Connection connection = connectionFactory.newConnection();
            channel = connection.createChannel();
```

If I add `setPort` then it sometimes causes TimeoutException, sometimes ConnectionRefused. I spent half a day to understand what was happening. Then I've commented out the setPort, everything works.

Note : I can see WebUI (http://localhost:15672) without any problem and server is up & running.

Why setPort breaks the connection initialization? Does RabbitMQ search all the ports to check available server? or does it use the default port 15672 ?

Comment: Isn't the [default port](https://www.rabbitmq.com/api-guide.html#connecting) `5672` instead of `15672`? Maybe this is why it works when you comment the line. You can try `setPort(5672)` as well.

Comment: Yes, it seems so. When I've checked through web gui and saw localhost:15672/# 
I thought the port must be the same. Still not sure why they differ

I was late to recognize it's a different working application on a different port ... thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [default port](https://www.rabbitmq.com/api-guide.html#connecting) is `5672`, not `15672`. This is why it works when you comment the line, it's setting the correct port as it's taking the default one. You can check this by calling `setPort(5672)` (although this is not necessary to set the port, but it will show that the issue is the port number and not the fact you're calling this function).